# Como obter uma string de um hbitmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bitmap

Tenho uma função que captura a imagem do monitor e cria um arquivo bitmap com o resultado, mas eu gostaria que retornasse uma string com o conteúdo que o arquivo teria, ao invés de escreve-lo ao disco.

A função:

```
int CaptureRegion(char *filename, int nLeft, int nTop, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow(); // Desktop handle
    HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd); // Desktop DC

    BITMAPINFO bi;
    void *pBits = NULL;
    ZeroMemory(&bi, sizeof(bi));
    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = nHeight;
    bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = nWidth;
    bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    // bitmap width should be aligned by DWORD under NT
    bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((nWidth * bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount +31)& ~31) /8 * nHeight; 

    HDC hBmpFileDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
    HBITMAP hBmpFileBitmap=CreateDIBSection(hDesktopDC,&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS,&pBits,NULL,0);
    SelectObject(hBmpFileDC, hBmpFileBitmap);
    BitBlt(hBmpFileDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDesktopDC, nLeft,nTop, SRCCOPY);
        HANDLE  hFile=CreateFile(filename,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    if(hFile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD   dwRet = 0;
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;

        ZeroMemory(&bfh, sizeof(bfh));
        bfh.bfType = 0x4D42;
        bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bfh.bfSize = bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage + bfh.bfOffBits;

        WriteFile(hFile, &bfh, sizeof(bfh), &dwRet, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, &bi.bmiHeader, sizeof(bi.bmiHeader), &dwRet, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, pBits, bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, &dwRet, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    } else return 0;
    DeleteDC(hBmpFileDC);
    DeleteObject(hBmpFileBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd,hDesktopDC);
        return 1;
}
```

Pelo que pesquisei, tenho que usar a função "GetDIBits", mas não sei como proceder.

Comment: Porque você quer obter string de um mapa de bits ? Qual é a utilidade?

Comment: Estou usando uma biblioteca em Lua(luapower/bitmap) que carrega o bitmap pelo arquivo, mas do modo que estou usando(tirando printscreen a cada segundo), não me agrada ficar escrevendo o arquivo no disco repetidas vezes, já que o uso apenas para procurar um pixel e depois o apago, para procurar na proxima imagem.

Comment: Se eu concatenasse o conteúdo do bfh, bi.bmiHeader e pBits, teria o conteúdo que o arquivo teria?

Comment: A você que criar um buffer não é uma string.

Comment: E como faço isso?

Comment: Eu não sei lua vou só criar o buffer, e **DI** de `GetDIBits` significa Device-Independent(Dispositivo independente) se você for usar o bitmap no mesmo dispositivo não precisa de `GetDIBits`  você vai precisar de `GetBitmapBits`.

Comment: Se você quer os bits para procurar um pixel não precisa de toda a "formalidade" do formato bitmap, pegue apenas os pixels da imagem(`pbits`) e retorne.

Comment: Mas preciso que seja bitmap, para o uso em Lua, preciso que tenha o conteúdo que o arquivo teria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você quer que a função retorne os dados do bitmap ao invés de escreve-los em um arquivo, certo? alterei o seu código um pouco para que a função retorne os dados na memória:

```
unsigned char* CaptureRegion(int nLeft, int nTop, int nWidth, int nHeight, unsigned int* size){
HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow(); // Desktop handle
HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd); // Desktop DC
unsigned char* image;

BITMAPINFO bi;
void *pBits = NULL;
ZeroMemory(&bi, sizeof(bi));
bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);
bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = nHeight;
bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = nWidth;
bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
// bitmap width should be aligned by DWORD under NT
bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((nWidth * bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount + 31)& ~31) / 8 * nHeight;

HDC hBmpFileDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
HBITMAP hBmpFileBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hDesktopDC, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pBits, NULL, 0);
SelectObject(hBmpFileDC, hBmpFileBitmap);
BitBlt(hBmpFileDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDesktopDC, nLeft, nTop, SRCCOPY);

DWORD   dwRet = 0;
BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;

ZeroMemory(&bfh, sizeof(bfh));
bfh.bfType = 0x4D42;
bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bfh.bfSize = bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage + bfh.bfOffBits;

*size = sizeof(bfh) + sizeof(bi.bmiHeader) + bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
image = new unsigned char[*size];

memcpy_s(image, sizeof(bfh), &bfh, sizeof(bfh));
memcpy_s(image + sizeof(bfh), sizeof(bi.bmiHeader), &bi.bmiHeader, sizeof(bi.bmiHeader));
memcpy_s(image + sizeof(bfh) + sizeof(bi.bmiHeader), bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, pBits, bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

DeleteDC(hBmpFileDC);
DeleteObject(hBmpFileBitmap);
ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);

return (unsigned char*)image;
}
```

No lugar de escrever em um arquivo você aloca memória sufciente pro bitmap, copia o conteúdo pra ela e retorna os dados. Se quiser ainda pode escreve-los em um arquivo:

```
unsigned char* image = CaptureRegion(0, 0, 500, 500, &size);

std::ofstream file("desktop.bmp", std::ios_base::out |std::ios_base::binary);

if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open file!\n";
    delete [] image;
    return 0;
}

file.write((char*)image, size);
file.close();
delete[] image;
```

obs: Também recomendo fazer checagem de erros com essas funções do windows :s

Comment: Fiz um teste, mas só retornou "BM60". Apenas o cabeçalho, acho que tem algo errado nos parametros da função memcpy_s, vou ver se descubro. Já é um grande avanço.

Comment: Funcionou como deveria, obrigado

Comment: memcpy_s é coisa do windows, ele pede apenas um parâmetro a mais que é o tamanho disponível no buffer de destino. O que estava errado?

Comment: Era erro humano(meu), seu código está bom. kk

Comment: Estou usando a função, para escrever um arquivo, funciona bem, mas quando uso o comando **sizeof** no valor que **CaptureRegion** retorna, sempre recebo **4** e só consigo usar tal valor para escrever um arquivo, nada mais.

Comment: O valor retornado é um ponteiro, ponteiros têm 4 bytes por isso sizeof retorna 4, olha direito o código que escreve a imagem no arquivo, eu uso a variável `size` pra obter o tamanho da imagem.

Comment: Certo, há como eu "copiar" o valor inteiro para uma **const char***? Não apenas **(const char*)image**, pois assim retornam apenas 4 bits, mas todo o valor.

Comment: sim, você pode usar `memcpy_s` ou até mesmo fazer um loop: `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)...`

Comment: Usando seu código, fiz esse programa: [link] http://pastebin.com/FZaNxPAR , ele escreve o arquivo corretamente, mas a saída não é a esperada, o mesmo acontece quando tento passar o valor para o Lua, sabe por quê pode ser?

Comment: A saída esta correta, você que programou errado, a variável `imagem` retornada pelas duas funções nada mais é do que um endereço de memória, o `std::cout` entende isso(`const char*`) como uma string e vai imprimr os dados até encontrar um `\0`, que por coincidência está logo após o identificador de bmp, só que os dados não são uma string, é uma imagem e não faz muito sentido(na maioria dos casos) tentar imprimi-la como uma string. A prova da correção é que o arquivo da imagem foi gerado corretamente! sobre a sua função lua você provavelmente também está utilizando ela de forma incorreta.

Comment: Recomendo estes links: https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/PRGSWB/Ponteiros/ponteiros.html

Comment: Tentei (*image), mas continua do mesmo jeito, pode dar mais uma luz?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49509/discussion-between-paulo-marcio-and-gabriel-sales).